# two tables primary keys as primary key to third table

Tags: hibernate

i am newbie to hibernate. I have two tables as below

```
Table1{id1 primary key;}

Table2{id2 primary key;}
```

one to many relationship is there between table1 to table2. implemented that relation, no issues. we also have third table as below

```
Table3{(id1 & id2) primary key,  col3 ,col4}
```

got a solution from googling to use as below in the third table mapping.

```
<composite-id>
     <key-property name="id1" column="id1" />
     <key-property name="id2" column="id2"/>
</composite-id>
```

pls suggest / guide me if there is a better/ advanced way to implement the same in hibernate. also suggest better way to save and retrieve objects.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest against this design; a primary key should always be a single column, technical key (i.e. no business relation of any kind).

In my schemas, I model this like so:

```
Table3( id primary key, table1fk foreign key, table2fk foreign key, col1, col2, ... )
```

Advantages:

- Same design for all tables
- Using foreign keys makes sure you can't accidentally delete the items in `Table1` or `Table2`
- Clear separation of concerns: A PK is used to locate and identify a row. Foreign keys mean: I'm referring to another table. Your design mixes the two

Comment: Hi Aaron, here one challenge is we want to make sure only one row exists for id1 and id2 combination at any time in third table. if we go with your design ...is it possible to achieve that with out much complexity?.